# TBrush bitmap alignment

Tags: alignment, c++builder, vcl, brush, c++builder-xe5

I have a `TPaintBox` control and have assigned the `TPaintBox->Canvas->Brush->Bitmap` to a prepared `TBitmap` with a grid pattern. The `TPaintBox` is client aligned inside it's parent (`Form`).

When I manually call `TPaintBox->Invalidate()` to redraw the control the brush is aligned perfectly at top,left (0,0 - left picture), but as soon I resize the window, the brush offset change to (20,7 - right picture) until I manually call `TPaintBox->Invalidate()` again.

[image]

I have tried to use one of the standard brush patterns such as `bsBDiagonal` and `bsCross`, but they all behave the same (different alignment between an `Invalidate()` call and `form` resize).

I tried to use the Win32 API `SetBrushOrgEx()` to manually set the brush alignment, but it has no effect on a window resize update. It does work perfectly well if I manually call `Invalidate()`.

If I set a breakpoint in my `onPaint` handler and check what the brush origo is, it always answer (0,0) even when it is misaligned.

I use `Canvas->RectFill()` to fill the background.

```
Canvas->Brush->Style = bsBDiagonal;
Canvas->FillRect(Client);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem in action?

Comment: @RemyLebeau. I can always rely on you :) I put this on hold, but I will see if I can create a short example.